# как разбить блок на отдельные блок javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как разбить блок на отдельные блок:

```
<span class="razmers">43,44,45</span>
```

Нужно разбить на:

```
<span class="razmers">
  <span class="razmer">43</span>
  <span class="razmer">44</span>
  <span class="razmer">45</span>
</span>
```

Вот так если делать, разбивает только на один блок

```
var tags =$(".product-razmer").find(".razmers").text();
    var re = /\s*,\s*/;
    var tagList = tags.split(re);
for (key in tagList) {
var item = tagList[key];
$(".razmers").append('<span class="razmer"></span>').text(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".razmers").each((i, e) => {
  var tags = $(e);
  var tagList = tags.text().split(',');

  tags.text('');
  for (const v of tagList) {
    tags.append(`<span class="razmer">${v}</span>`);
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="razmers">40,41,42</div>
<div class="razmers">43,44,45</div>
```

Comment: Работает, но у меня, сейчас в блок добавляются все размеры на странице, у меня верстка такая: 
```
<div class="product-razmer">
              <span>Размеры:</span>
              <span class="razmers">43,44</span>
            </div>
<div class="product-razmer">
              <span>Размеры:</span>
              <span class="razmers">45,42</span>
            </div>
```
Нужно что бы в свой блок, добавлялись свои размеры, я думал find() поможет

Comment: @ilyaaa521, поправил под Ваша нужду.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `$(".razmers").append('<span class="razmer"></span>').text(item);` — здесь, когда добавляете тег через append, вы хотели бы потом в этот же тег добавить `.text(item)` а jQuery думает иначе - он возвращает всё тот же `".razmers"`, чей текст заменяется на item, стирая добавленный тег.

```js
$(".sizes").each(function() {
  let numbers = $(this).text().match(/\d+/g) || []; // (*1)
  $(this).html( numbers.map(n => '<span class="size">' + n + '</span>') ); // (*2)
});
```

```css
.size { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid orange; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="sizes">43,44,45</span><br>
<span class="sizes">36,46,47</span>
```

**(*1)** `.match(/\d+/g)` — Достанет все числа из строки в виде массива. Или, вернет null если ничего не найдет. Чтобы дальше не было ошибки, для этого предусмотрен `||` "или" пустой массив.

**(*2)** Во-первых, после [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) на выходе получается массив вида

                                 `["<span>43</span>", "<span>44</span>", "<span>45</span>"]`

Во-вторых, сам не знал:
    Если в jQuery-`.html()` передать массив вместо строки, он сам соберет из неё строку)

Если без jQ, написать там `this.innerHTML = [1, 2, 3]` — между элементами останутся запятые. Чтобы избавиться от них, после map можно было бы добавить `.join("");`